# Convergence of a product of sequences convergent in mean when one of them is bounded

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Suppose $X_n\to X$ in $L^1$ and $V_n\to V$ in $L^1$ and $(V_n)$ is a bounded sequence. I'm trying to show that then $\mathbb{E}X_nV_n\to \mathbb{E}XV$.

One has for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$
$$|\mathbb{E}X_nV_n-\mathbb{E}XV_n+\mathbb{E}XV_n-\mathbb{E}XV|\leq 
\mathbb{E}|V_n||X_n-X|+N\mathbb{E}(V_n-V)1_{\{|X|\leq N, V_n\geq V\}}+
N\mathbb{E}(V-V_n)1_{\{|X|\leq N, V\geq V_n\}}+|\mathbb{E}X(V_n-V)1_{\{|X|>N\}}|.$$
Now the first three members on the right converge to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. How does one go about the last one? Or maybe it should be done some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the last term, use 
$$
|\mathbb{E} X(V_n-V) 1_{|X|>N}| \leq C |\mathbb{E} X 1_{\{|X|>N\}}|,
$$
where $C$ is our bound on $V_n$.  So using your argument above you get a bound like
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} |\mathbb{E}X_nV_n - \mathbb{E}XV| \leq 
C |\mathbb{E} X1_{\{|X|>N\}}|,
$$
which holds for all $N$.  But $X\in L^1$, so as $N\to\infty$ the right hand side goes to $0$.  Thus the limit on the left is $0$, so $\mathbb{E}X_nV_n\to \mathbb{E}XV$.

Comment: But how do we know that $V$ is bounded? We know that $V$ is integrable, but I think it does not mean that it is bounded?

Comment: By "$V_n$ is a bounded sequence" I assumed you meant that we had a uniform pointwise bound $|V_n(x)|\leq C$.  This implies $V$ is bounded.

Comment: How does it follow from the boundedness of $V_n$?

Comment: Since $V_n\to V$ in $L^1$, up to a subsequence $V_n\to V$ pointwise almost everywhere.  Thus $V(x)$ is a.e. the limit of a uniformly bounded sequence, so $|V(x)|\leq C$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, but the bound holds almost everywhere. Well, anyway, it probably works if we change $V$ with $V'$ where $V'$ is zero on the set where $V$ is not bounded. Basically that was my question, I should have probably stated it that way, I just thought it didn't work. Thanks.